# Array of Structs memory realloc stderr

Tags: c, memory, allocation, realloc

I am trying to realloc an array of structs when it runs out of space as I'm putting elements into it but I keep receiving a realloc stderr. The array of struct will eventually have 235,000 elements in it. When I set the initial start size to 100,000 I receive the stderr when trying to realloc. If I se the initial start size to 300,000 it does not give the error because it never reaches the realloc statement.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERLEN 200
#define START_SIZE 100000
#define GROW 1000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct{
    char *forw;
    char *back;
} word;

typedef struct{
    char *entry;
} single_words;


FILE *words;
/*-------------Function Prototypes------------*/
void reverse(char* string, char* revstr, int len);
int search_struct(char* find, word* words, int length);
int compare(const void* eventa, const void* eventb);
int length(char* string);


int main(void)
{
    char *buffer;
    int letter_index[26];
    char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i=0, found = FALSE, strlen=0, letter=0;
    word *word_storage;
    single_words *output_storage;
    int num_words = 0, size = 0;
    int num_output = 0, output_size = 0;

    /*buffer for the input strings of the words in the input file*/
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*BUFFERLEN);
        if(!buffer){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in buffer string mem alloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }   

    /*Initializing the array of structs to store the forward and reverse of each word*/
    word_storage = (word*) malloc (sizeof(word)*START_SIZE);
        if(!word_storage){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in word_storage string mem alloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        size = START_SIZE;

    /*Initializing the array of structs for the output*/
    output_storage = (single_words*) malloc (sizeof(single_words)*START_SIZE);
        if(!output_storage){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in output_storage mem alloc\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        output_size = START_SIZE;   

    /*Set the letter index 0(which is a) to the first character*/
    letter_index[0] = 0;

    words = fopen("words", "r");

    /*Read the words(forward and reverse) in from stdin into the word_storage*/
    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERLEN, words) != NULL){
        buffer = strtok(buffer, "\n");
        strlen = length(buffer);
        if (num_words < size){
            /*Allocate memory for the forward and reverse strings*/
            word_storage[num_words].forw = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen);
                if(!word_storage[num_words].forw){
                    free(word_storage[num_words].forw);
                    fprintf(stderr, "word_storage forward string malloc was unsuccessful");
                    exit(1);
                }
            word_storage[num_words].back = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen);
                if(!word_storage[num_words].back){
                    free(word_storage[num_words].back);
                    fprintf(stderr, "word_storage forward string malloc was unsuccessful");
                    exit(1);;
                }               

            /*Store the forward and reverse in the strings*/
            strncpy(word_storage[num_words].forw, buffer, strlen);
            reverse(word_storage[num_words].forw, word_storage[num_words].back, strlen);
            printf("%d: %s %s\n", num_words, word_storage[num_words].forw, word_storage[num_words].back);

            /*Increment the letter if it changes*/
            if(word_storage[num_words].forw[0] != alpha[letter]){
                letter++;
                letter_index[letter] = num_words + 1;
            }
            num_words++;
        }
        else{
            /*Increase the size of word_storage*/
            word_storage = (word*) realloc (word_storage, sizeof(word) * size * GROW);
                if(!word_storage){
                    free(word_storage);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error in word_storage realloc string mem realloc\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            size = size * GROW;
        }       
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The realloc error occurs here:

```
word_storage = (word*) realloc (word_storage, sizeof(word) * size * GROW);
    if(!word_storage){
      free(word_storage);
      fprintf(stderr, "Error in word_storage realloc string mem realloc\n");
      exit(1);
     }
     size = size * GROW;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you initially set `size` to `START_SIZE`, which is 100,000. Then when you use that up, you try to allocate `sizeof(word) * size * GROW` bytes. `sizeof(word)` is presumably 16 bytes; we know that `size` is 100000, and `GROW` is 1000. So that works out to enough space for 100,000,000 entries, of which you say you will use 235,000. That seems like the allocation is a bit on the generous side.

The total space for 100,000,000 entries is 1,600,000,000 bytes. That seems like a lot, although these days many desktop machines could handle that. But it doesn't seem *too* surprising that `realloc` fails.

Perhaps you should make `GROW` something more reasonable, like 2.

By the way, once you've established that word_storage is NULL, there is no point in calling `free(word_storage)`. It does no harm, since `free(NULL)` is a no-op, but it also does no good for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying the size by 1000 which is too much (highly exponential growth 1 -> 1000 -> 1000 000 -> 1000 000 000 ...), and you are not displaying the `errno`. I suggest instead

```
 size_t newsize = 3*size/2 + 1000;
 word_storage = realloc(word_storage, sizeof(word)*newsize);
 if (!word_storage) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Cannot grow storage to %ld size, %s\n",
                     (long) newsize, strerror(errno));
     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 else size = newsize;
```

then if starting with an initial size of 1000, you are getting the much more reasonable progression 1000 -> 2500 -> 4750 -> 8125 -> 13187 -> 20780 ... and more importantly you are spending at most 50% of useless memory, not a factor of nearly 1000!